# How to get Kotlin Collection<*> info with reflection?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

Is there a way to know information of collection?

```
fun foo(clazz: Class<*>) {
  // 1. How to know clazz is collection?
  // 2. How to know T of Collection<T> is String?
}

fun myFunc() {
  val mySet: HashSet<String> = HashSet()
  foo(mySet::class.java)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean compile time or runtime? Because at runtime it's impossible to determine the generic type due to type erasure.

Comment: @Pawel I mean runtime. I have to other way now. Thanks